# Copy files from Bitbucket via Jenkins to a production server

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket

I have got my code files in bitbucket and have configured a jenkins build job to run where there is a change in the bitbucket repository. At the end of which it has to copy the files from the repo to a directory located at a production server from where the application is running.

Is there a away to copy the files from repo to a server using a script inputed to jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

I asume you have the files in the workspace of the job. How about copying the files via the command line? If you want to do so, insert a batch block for windows nodes or a shell block for linux nodes and use

```
cp original_file new_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 possibilites:

**Run a slave on the production server**

In this case you run a slave on the production server, which connects to your master jenkins. The slave has to be run under a user, which is able to write the directory, where you want to copy the files too.

2 Variations of this possibility:

1. You can execute the clone (checkout) of the bitbucket repository on the master and then use stash to make the files accessible on the slave, running on the production server (https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build).
2. You run the whole pipeline on the slave, which is running on the production server, which means the production server needs access to bitbucket.

There are several possibilities to connect a slave to a master: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingagents

**Use remote copy possibilites**

You copy the files with eg. `scp` in linux.

This has some security implications:

- You have to add the password of the production to the jenkins credential store and pass it to the copy command
- if using keys (recommended). You have to add the private key to the jenkins credential store and pass it to the command.